# Bash 4.2 doesn't complete directory names

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a problem with `bash` completion after a system upgrade.

```
$ mkdir abcde    
$ cd abc[TAB]
```

does nothing, while in the older `bash` versions it would expand to `$ cd abcde`.

Some older forum on `bash` suggests setting the `direxpand` option, but seemingly it is missing in the `bash 4.2`:

```
$ shopt -s direxpand  
bash: shopt: direxpand: invalid shell option name
```

(I have upgraded from Fedora 11 to Fedora 17 with its `bash-4.2.37`)

Is there a way around it?

Comment: You're mixing up expansion and completion, which are two different things. Your version of Bash indeed doesn't have the `direxpand` option yet, but all `direxpand` would do is *expand* a directory from a variable, e.g. `dir=/usr/local`, and then you could expand `$dir/somewhere/else` to `/usr/local/somewhere/else` by pressing *Tab*. Bash should always complete directory names. Are you sure there aren't any other files/directories in your current directory starting with `abc`? Have you tried pressing *Tab* twice?

Answer (score 2):

bash uses the readline library for input, <kbd>tab</kbd> should map to the readline `complete` operation (this is distinct from the bash command of the same name, though related in operation).

There are a number of possible causes, things to check are:

- test to see if any of the other completions work: `meta-?` (probably <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>`)
  this should list all matches (similar to pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> twice)
- check to see if `ctrl-i` works instead (alternate way of entering tab)
- check your `TERM` variable, and the output of `stty` (should not contain any reference to tab)
- check what bash completion features may be defined, run `complete` with no arguments to list them
- your `readline` may be messed up, check `/etc/inputrc` and your `~/.inputrc` (if any), and the output of `bind -q complete`. It should contain at least "`\C-i`" meaning <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> (tab)
- check to see if anything has broken readline key sequence for tab: `bind -S`  (should not contain "`\C-i`")
- If you run `bind '"\C-i": complete'` does it start working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently shopt -s direxpand works with everything *except* the
built-in "cd". So I just added "alias xy=cd" to my profile, and
xy works just like cd except direxpand works using TAB. (Who would have
thought it would be so simple?)